# Why is UART communication on ESP32 giving back random data?

Tags: embedded, esp32, uart

I'm using the [UART echo exmaple](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/peripherals/uart/uart_echo/main/uart_echo_example_main.c) to test UART communication between the ESP32 and the raspberry pi 4.

Modified ESP32 code:

```
* UART Echo Example

   This example code is in the Public Domain (or CC0 licensed, at your option.)

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, this
   software is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
   CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "driver/uart.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "esp_log.h"

/**
 * This is an example which echos any data it receives on configured UART back to the sender,
 * with hardware flow control turned off. It does not use UART driver event queue.
 *
 * - Port: configured UART
 * - Receive (Rx) buffer: on
 * - Transmit (Tx) buffer: off
 * - Flow control: off
 * - Event queue: off
 * - Pin assignment: see defines below (See Kconfig)
 */

#define ECHO_TEST_TXD (CONFIG_EXAMPLE_UART_TXD)
#define ECHO_TEST_RXD (CONFIG_EXAMPLE_UART_RXD)
#define ECHO_TEST_RTS (UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE)
#define ECHO_TEST_CTS (UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE)

#define ECHO_UART_PORT_NUM      (UART_NUM_1)
#define ECHO_UART_BAUD_RATE     (CONFIG_EXAMPLE_UART_BAUD_RATE)
#define ECHO_TASK_STACK_SIZE    (CONFIG_EXAMPLE_TASK_STACK_SIZE)

static const char *TAG = "UART TEST";

#define BUF_SIZE (1024)

static void echo_task(void *arg)
{
    /* Configure parameters of an UART driver,
     * communication pins and install the driver */
    uart_config_t uart_config = {
        .baud_rate = 19200,
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity    = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
        .source_clk = UART_SCLK_DEFAULT,
    };
    int intr_alloc_flags = 0;

#if CONFIG_UART_ISR_IN_IRAM
    intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_IRAM;
#endif

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_driver_install(ECHO_UART_PORT_NUM, BUF_SIZE * 2, 0, 0, NULL, intr_alloc_flags));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_param_config(ECHO_UART_PORT_NUM, &uart_config));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_set_pin(ECHO_UART_PORT_NUM, 2, 16, ECHO_TEST_RTS, ECHO_TEST_CTS));

    // Configure a temporary buffer for the incoming data
    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *) malloc(BUF_SIZE);

    while (1) {
        // Read data from the UART
        int len = uart_read_bytes(ECHO_UART_PORT_NUM, data, (BUF_SIZE - 1), 2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        // Write data back to the UART
        uart_write_bytes(ECHO_UART_PORT_NUM, (const char *) data, len);
        if (len) {
            data[len] = '\0';
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Recv str: %s", (char *) data);
        }
    }
}

void app_main(void)
{
    xTaskCreate(echo_task, "uart_echo_task", ECHO_TASK_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 10, NULL);
}
```

Code on raspberry pi:

```
import serial
import time
import os
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=19200, timeout=5)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    by = os.urandom(32)
    ser.write(by)
    rx = ser.read(32)
    print(rx)
    print(len(rx))
    print(by)
```

Raspberry pi code output:

```
#Output from UART
b"RE\x14w\xd9Ac2G@1\x13V'\xccuM!\xd5w\x90"
#Length of output
21
#Original data (32 bytes)
b'\xaa\xc5\x89w\xcfc\x8c\xbc\x9cN\xcbGB/\xb3m\xd2\xae\xd3*\xa3\xae_\x83\xf1I\xfd\xed\xf7\x0f\xf9'
```

I remember getting it working before, but now it is stuck like this.

First I tried to communicate with UART using an ESP CAM, then I tried using an ESP32-WROOM. Both of them did the same thing. I also tried using UART_NUM_1.

Update:

After doing some debugging, I found out that the ESP32 receives 40 bytes when I'm sending 16. Is the UART just broken?

Answer (score 0):

I plugged both the boards together and tested uart, it worked. The problem was on the rpi